# Does CrossFilter.js work with flot and morris charts

Tags: javascript, web, flot, crossfilter

Does CrossFilter.js work with morris and flot charts? 
Basically I want to understand is crossfilter.js independent of the visualization?

The functionality I would like to observe is that if I have multiple charts visualizing  a dataset, the selection in one chart should be reflected in the others.

I have written the backend in python using flask.

P.S - Relatively new to web programming. Looking to visualize a quick and dirty prototype.

Comment: Yes, Crossfilter is independent of the visualization. The only visualization library I'm aware of that specifically works with Crossfilter is dc.js, so that's what I'd recommend you look at. You may also want to look at Vega as the new 2.0 version includes interaction definitions, which allow filtering across multiple views. Other visualization libraries can be used with Crossfilter, but you'll have to trigger updates/redraws yourself when the data or filters change.